# Convert Flash to MP3

Tags: file, flash, audio, mp3, swfobject

I'm trying to convert the SWF file from this URL to MP3 file:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/learning/schoolradio/subjects/english/oliver_twist/episodes/episode_1

I have no idea how to even get the SWF file and I'll really appreciate if someone will help me!

Thank you very much! Really appreciate this!

Comment: SWF file is just an app (code etc) which most likely loads an external MP3 or AAC file anyway. Just saying don't assume "getting the SWF" data is magically convertable to MP3 audio.... PS: Wrong question for this site, its for programmers needing help with their own code .

Comment: @VC.One I am a programmer, I want to download the MP3 and implement it on my app. Do you know how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not helping you steal content from the BBC. You can't just copy & paste other company's content into your app and pass it around like its all your own. Ask or hire friends to do an original reading (voice actors). Problem solved!! Anyways on this site, you show your code attempt then maybe someone can suggest why its not working. Check your browser's network activity tool for a clue to possible links.